# Material Design lite tooltip positioning

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using `material design lite` library but I have an issue. When i reduce the window and sometimes the tooltip isn't `positioning` properly and is also taking `2 lines` instead of `one`.

Html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Rich Tooltip -->

    <button  id="tt3" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
    <div  class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--top   " data-mdl-for="tt3">
    Upload <strong>file.zip</strong>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
#tt3
{
  position:fixed;
  right:24px;
  bottom:24px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.mdl-tooltip.mdl-tooltip--top{ width:70px;}
```

```css
#tt3
{
  position:fixed;
  right:24px;
  bottom:24px;

}

.mdl-tooltip.mdl-tooltip--top{
  width:70px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 
    <!-- Rich Tooltip -->

    <button  id="tt3" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
    <div  class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--top   " data-mdl-for="tt3">
    Upload <strong>file.zip</strong>
    </div>
```